# When is the session id/authentication token generated when accessing certain sites?

Tags: networking, cookies, session

The question title doesn't do a very good job at explaining what exactly my question is, so I'll elaborate:

When accessing most websites (in this question I'll just use twitter.com as an example), the first request that is made is to the website URL:

[image: (image)]

Even though this is the first time the client connects to the server (as far as I know) the request headers still contain a ton of information, including a session token:

[image: (blurred token)]

How can this token be generated despite the client not having any previous contact with the server? (Again, as far as I know.)

I apologize if I'm missing something basic and fundamental, but I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my head around how this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies are stored in your browser. The browser just sends back the cookies to the server that it got from the server. On the (actual) first connection, there will be no cookies, including no session cookies (you can simulate that by deleting all the cookies in your browser). On subsequent connections, the browser will send the cookie it got the last time.

So in your example, you (or someone else) already used your browser to connect to Twitter. That's why the cookie is sent.

The cookies are always generated in the server of the website you are connecting to. They are never generated in your browser.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. At first, I was confused, as the session id still showed up even after clearing cookies. That's when I realized that the chrome search autocomplete sends a request to the site (probably in order to get its icon). Clearing the cookies after entering in the full URL gave me the expected result.

Comment: Yes, cookies will also be set when requesting the icon (if the server is programmed this way).